# sed removes one backslash from the variable

Tags: bash, sed

i am writing bash script and i have a variable

```
TYPE="type=\$(echo \"\$type\" | sed 's|/|\\/|g' )"
```

that i want to insert to a text file

tried to  insert to line 15 using sed

```
sed -i "15i$TYPE"  filename
```

the line that should be inserted to the  file should be

```
type=$(echo "$type" | sed 's|/|\\/|g' )
```

but i am getting:

```
type=$(echo "$type" | sed 's|/|\/|g' )
```

There is one backslash  missing, how can i get the required output with the 2 backslashes.

Comment: Thank you ,but i am getting the same exact line as i did before

Answer (score 2):

Use here-doc to avoid unnecessary escaping:

```
read -r TYPE <<-'EOF'
type=$(echo "$type" | sed 's|/|\\\\/|g' )
EOF
```

Remember you need to enter `\\` for each `\`.

Then use it as:

```
sed -i "15i$TYPE" filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You get one backslash for a pair inside double-quotes - just use two pairs

```
TYPE="type=\$(echo \"\$type\" | sed 's|/|\\\\/|g' )"
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `TYPE` is not getting double backlash:

```
$ TYPE="type=\$(echo \"\$type\" | sed 's|/|\\/|g' )"
$ echo "$TYPE"
type=$(echo "$type" | sed 's|/|\/|g' )
```

There are several ways to get the value inside `TYPE` to contain the correct string:

- Convert each needed `\` to an escaped `\\` one:

  ```
  $ TYPE="type=\$(echo \"\$type\" | sed 's|/|\\\\/|g' )"; echo "$TYPE"
  type=$(echo "$type" | sed 's|/|\\/|g' )
  ```
- Use single quotes as the external container:

  ```
  $ TYPE='type=$(echo "$type" | sed '\''s|/|\\/|g'\'' )'; echo "$TYPE"
  type=$(echo "$type" | sed 's|/|\\/|g' )
  ```
- use printf as a helper:

  ```
  $ printf -v TYPE '%s' 'type=$(echo "$type" | sed '\''s|/|\\/|g'\'' )'; echo "$TYPE"
  type=$(echo "$type" | sed 's|/|\\/|g' )
  ```
- Use C strings style:

  ```
  $ TYPE=$'type=$(echo "$type" | sed \047s|/|\\\\/|g\047';echo "$TYPE"
  type=$(echo "$type" | sed 's|/|\\/|g'
  ```
- Or use the `-r` option of read to avoid converting the `\\`:

  ```
  $ read -r TYPE <<\EOF
  > type=$(echo "$type" | sed 's|/|\\/|g'
  > EOF

  $ echo "$TYPE"
  type=$(echo "$type" | sed 's|/|\\/|g'
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To change `/` to `\` in a variable using bash is just:

```
$ type='a/b/c'
$ type="${type//\//\\}"
$ echo "$type"
a\b\c
```

i.e. no need for sed. If you want to put a line that does that in a file like:

```
$ cat file
a
b
c
d
```

then that's either of these:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{var=ARGV[1]; ARGV[1]=""} NR==3{print var}1' 'type="${type//\//\\}"' file
a
b
type="${type//\//\\}"
c
d

$ var='type="${type//\//\\}"' awk 'NR==3{print ENVIRON["var"]}1' file
a
b
type="${type//\//\\}"
c
d
```

Change the `3` above to `15` or whatever you like.